# Draggable div doesn't want to move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable

i created a method that generate my table and inside table cell i added a div. I want to move that div across a table (in his cells), but my div doesn't want to move. Any ideas ?

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <%@ include file="/resources/js/dynamicTable.js" %></script>
                <button id="add_table" onclick="createDiv()">Add Table</button>

    <div class="static_form_room" id="static_form_room">
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    <%@ include file="/resources/js/generateTable.js" %>
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">tableCreate();</script>
</div>
```

**dymanicTable.js**

```
function createDiv() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var body = document.getElementById('room').rows[0].cells[0];//room is my table id
    body.innerHTML = '';

    var img = $('#res_table').css('background-image');
    var width = $('#res_table').css('width');
    var height = $('#res_table').css('height');
    var bg_repeat = $('#res_table').css('background-repeat');
    var bg_size = $('#res_table').css('background-size');
    div.className = 'ui-widget-content';
    div.id = 'dynamicTable';
    div.style.backgroundImage = img;
    div.style.width = width;
    div.style.height = height;
    div.style.backgroundRepeat = bg_repeat;
    div.style.backgroundSize = bg_size;
    div.cursor = 'move';
    body.appendChild(div);
}
$(function() {
    $( "#dynamicTable" ).draggable();
});
```

Comment: your javascript isn't in a script tag... If this is a separate file, might want to separate the code into multiple blocks

Comment: a demo or fiddle would help

Comment: @getoffmylawn dynamicTable.js and generateTable.js are two separe js files, and the method createDiv() is inside dymanicTable.js. It creates the div but doesn't move

Comment: @getoffmylawn i added the methods in the same jsp file, but still, doesn't move

Comment: Could you replace your Server side code with the actual output. That would be helpful, or as previously stated, a http://jsfiddle.net demo would be helpful